# Which index types do not support online index rebuilds?

Tags: sql-server-2012, index, index-tuning, performance, performance-tuning

In SQL Server 2012 Enterprise Ed., which index types do not support online index rebuilds?
and why?
and which activity-operations can prevent online index rebuilds?

[image]

Comment: I strongly recommend using a well-tested 3rd party solution to do index and statistics maintenance. Many of these are script-based and cost $0. Regardless, clobbering all the indexes every time this runs (and then updating stats, which isn't even necessary) is an incredible waste of resources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is in [the documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190981.aspx):

> - Clustered indexes must be created, rebuilt, or dropped offline when the underlying table contains the following large object (LOB) data types: image, ntext, and text.
> - Nonunique nonclustered indexes can be created online when the table contains LOB data types but none of these columns are used in the index definition as either key or nonkey (included) columns.
> - Indexes on local temp tables cannot be created, rebuilt, or dropped online. This restriction does not apply to indexes on global temp tables.

Other limitations and considerations are listed as well.